# Enable the bottom volume bar by default on TradingView

Tags: reactjs, tradingview-api

I upgraded the tradingview to the new version, and now the bottom volume bars are gone and I have to go to the indicators and select volume to see the bottom bars.
This is the picture of the chart now:
[image]
Now I want to turn it on by deault.

I've changed the datafeed apis according to the new version and now I can see the bars as well.